# The ASP.NET web application stopped working in local Network and Access DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ms-access, localhost

I developed web application ( Electronic Exam web Application ) for students, used these tools..

**1-Language:** asp.net
**2-DB System:** MS Access 2010
**3-Network:** Local
**4-Browser:** Google Chrome
**5-Web server:** IIS
**6-Computer system:** core i3
**7-OS:** Windows7

***The problem:*
The system began to work well at first and gave excellent results, but with repeated use and running new sessions occurred suspended and stopped in the web application.
How I can solve this problem ?**

Comment: you have to provide more information and details. for example error messages, exceptions and etc.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing like that. @Meysam

Comment: there should be some log in windows event viewer. You can use that one to see the problem. And if you did design the application you can add Elmah to see all your exceptions